# Facebook PHP sdk is posting twice on my wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hey guys,
I have a little problem and I don't know how can I fix it.
I have this function:

```
public function postOnUserWall($message, $linkTitle=false, $link=false, $description=false, $picture=false) {
$attachment = array(
        'message' => $message
    );
    if ($linkTitle != false) {
        $attachment['name'] = $linkTitle;
    }
    if ($link != false) {
        $attachment['link'] = $link;
    }
    if ($description != false) {
        $attachment['description'] = $description;
    }
    if ($picture != false) {
        $attachment['picture'] = $picture;
    }

    try {
        $publishStream = $this->facebook->api("/" . $this->user . "/feed", 'post', $attachment);
        //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the cbase url
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        d($e);
    }
}
```

I am using Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be enough information here to answer your question. How are you calling the function? Other than double posting, what else are you seeing the script do? Do your webserver logs show the script getting executed twice?

Comment: I have a problem, Here's the code, I don't know how to fix it.., What do you think that you have missed anything ?

Comment: No isn't called twice. Single time call and the server doesn't report any double posting!. That is the ideea . And on my wall the posts posted at 2 sec one after the other.

Comment: Have you tried any logging to ensure that this function isn't being called twice? KLogger is pretty sweet and takes no time to get going. http://codefury.net/2008/07/klogger-a-simple-logging-class-for-php/

Answer (score 0):

check and make sure the no redirect is done when user accesses that page / function.
some people get this problem becuase after they do the publishing, they check for certain conditions and then do a redirection again (so as to handle the authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i tried to post on a application fanpage.
I think the problem is NOT with the programing.
I solved the problem by editing the permissions of the applikation fanpage and auth dialog of the application.

- setup application: Auth Dialog `->` Default Activity Privacy:None
- setup application page (target page): manage permissions `->`
- People can write or post content on the wall `-->` no
- People can add photos and videos `-->` yes
- People can add tags to photos by (Application Name) `-->` yes/no

Hope this helps :-)